# Why the code stops working when I start using localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

The code below is only working when I remove the componentWillMount that uses localStorage. With usage localStorage it gives a mistake

> this.state.interests.map is not a function

I tried to move usage of localStorage out of component but it won't help. I suppose that using local storage somehow changes this.state.interests that they stop being an array.

```js
let interests = ["Музыка", "Компьютеры", "Радио"]
let ListOfInterest = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {value: '', interests: interests};
  },
  componentWillMount() {
    let local = localStorage.getItem('interests')
    if (local) {
      this.setState({interests: local});
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('interests', this.state.interests)}
  },
  deleteInterest(key) {
    delete interests[key]
    this.setState(this.state) // without this line the page will not re-render
  },
  addInterest() {
    interests.unshift(this.state.value)
    this.setState({value: ''})
  },
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value})
  },
  render() {
    return <div className="interests">
      <b>Интересы</b>
      <br/>
      {this.state.interests.map((int, index) => {
        return <button onClick={() => {
          this.deleteInterest(index)
        }} key={index} className="btn-interest">{int}</button>
      })}
      <input type='text' placeholder="Add" value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
      <button onClick={() => {
        this.addInterest()
      }} className="add">Add interest</button>

    </div>
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have to stringify the array before storing it in local storage, and unstringify (parse) it on the way back out.

Comment: `this.setState(this.state)` looks horrible!

Comment: check if your local in componentWillMount() is an array or not

Comment: Are you working with the author of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788157/warning-js45-warning-setstate-can-only-update-a-mounted-or-mounting-comp ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14394894)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your example

1. in `localStorage.setItem` second argument have to be a `String`, you can not store `Array`(*when you do it, in storage will be string separated by coma because called method `toString` - `[1, 2, 3].toString()`* ), you need [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) array before set to Storage

   > [`keyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) A DOMString containing the value you want to give the
   >   key you are creating/updating.

   ```
   localStorage.setItem(
      'interests', JSON.stringify(this.state.interests)
   )
   ```

   and [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) when get value

   ```
   let local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('interests'));
   ```
2. `this.setState(this.state)` this is not good way to update state, you need update state like so

   ```
   deleteInterest(key) {
     this.setState({
       interests: this.state.interests.filter((el, i) => i !== key)
     })
   },

   addInterest() {
     this.setState({ 
       value: '', 
       interests: this.state.interests.concat(this.state.value)
     });
   },
   ```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/63228/)